# how does entityframework save changes work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I am trying to save 2 entity into two different table and these have related by one to one. but there is something weird for me. look below code please

```
     public int CreateNotification(BusinessModel.Notification notification)
{
    var db = new DataAccess.ApplicationDbContext();
    var dbNotification = new DataAccess.Notification()
    {
        Name = notification.Name,
    };

    db.Notifications.Add(dbNotification);

    //set NotificationSchedule
    var dbNotificationSchedule = new  DataAccess.NotificationSchedule()
    {
        Schedule = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notification.NotificationSchedule)
    };
    db.NotificatoinSchedule.Add(dbNotificationSchedule);

    ***db.SaveChanges();***
```

this code works and the *Foreign key* of Notification is set to Notification schedule right. ***BUT the question is how*** the Id of notification is set to the Id of notificatioschedule? if I Add the related entity after the savechange there is an error, "update entity error...."

```
var db = new DataAccess.ApplicationDbContext();
var dbNotification = new DataAccess.Notification()
{
    Name = notification.Name,
};

db.Notifications.Add(dbNotification);

***db.SaveChanges();***

//set NotificationSchedule
var dbNotificationSchedule = new  DataAccess.NotificationSchedule()
{
    Schedule = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notification.NotificationSchedule)
};
db.NotificatoinSchedule.Add(dbNotificationSchedule);
```

}

```
public class Notification
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual NotificationSchedule NotificationSchedules { get; set; }

}



   public class NotificationSchedule
    {
        [ForeignKey("Notification")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Schedule { get; set; }
        public virtual Notification Notification { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: can you please post the classes you use for `Notification` and `NotificationSchedule`, be more precise about the exception you get.

Comment: i added my classes, nut my real question is not about the exception, I want to know the process behind the scene of EF! in the first scenario why both entity are added with right foreign key, while I do not set foreign key explicitly! we have two independet Object, dbnotification and dbnotificationschedule but the Id of first table will be set to dependant table , I do not know why, thanks

Comment: i understand the question, but the requested information may help to answer. Is the exception a duplicate row exception or something else. Right now, in your code, nothing explicitly set the relation.

Comment: looking at your code i don't see how you are associating the notification with the schedule.  i would expect to see something like dbNotification.NotificationSchedules = new NotificationSchedule(); but you just new it up and add it to the context.

Comment: EXACTLY, my question is this actually, why does this code without no associating works? after the save change the ID of both table is same, as we expect with right associating, and that's why I say this is weird for me,